# Node express request goes to other endpoint in router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't figure this out. Why is it my request:

```
localhost:3000/api/customers/search?q=glenn
```

Goes to:

```
  // Retrieve a single Customer with customerId
  router.get("/:customerId", customers.findOne);
```

when it is supposed to go to here???

```
// Search for a customer.
  router.get("/search/:q", customers.search)
```

---

**customer.routes.js**

```
module.exports = app => {
  const customers = require("../controllers/customer.controller");

  const router = require("express").Router();

  // Create a new Customer
  router.post("/", customers.create);

  // Retrieve all Customers
  router.get("/", customers.findAll);

  // Search for a customer.
  router.get("/search/:q", customers.search)

  // Retrieve a single Customer with customerId
  router.get("/:customerId", customers.findOne);

  // Update a Customer with customerId
  router.put("/:customerId", customers.update);

  // Delete a Customer with customerId
  router.delete("/:customerId", customers.delete);

  // Create a new Customer
  router.delete("/", customers.deleteAll);

  app.use("/api/customers", router)
};
```

**Morgan + Sequelize logs:**

> Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `email`, `name`, `active`,
>   `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `customers` AS `customer` WHERE
>   `customer`.`id` = 'search'; ::1 - - [25/Apr/2020:16:41:06 +0000] "GET
>   /api/customers/search?q=glenn HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-"
>   "PostmanRuntime/7.24.1"

Comment: From  the logs, it is searching. Check your search method. That is not findone call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your request doesn't match what the router is looking for, either change your request from `localhost:3000/api/customers/search?q=glenn` to `localhost:3000/api/customers/search/glenn`

OR

change `router.get("/search/:q", customers.search)` to `router.get("/search", customers.search)`

Comment: I did that router change. Now in my controller, I can't get the query string. ```console.log("Search for: " + req.params.q)``` says ```Search for: undefined```

Comment: you'll have to change that to `req.query.q`

Comment: Thanks! `req.query.q` solved it. I thought there were only `req.params` and `req.body`.

Comment: query come from anything after the `?` in the url, params references your "dynamic" part of the route, e.g. `:q`, and body is what's sent to the endpoint

Answer (score 1):

you need another route to handle, search without "/:r".

`/search/:q` only works for query like

- `/search/test`
- `/search/something`

**Not**

- `/search?q=something`

**Update:**

```
// Search for a customer.
  router.get("/search/:q", customers.search)

// Add this
// Search for a for query.
  router.get("/search", customers.search)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. The explanation helped big time, but Joe's comment pointed my error. This answer + Joel's comment solved the problem.